# Is it possible to have php hosted local connects to Amazon dynamoDb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, lamp, nosql

I was working on a Arduino project that provides data to outside public but I want to keep only for family members or some guests. So I wanted to set up login authentication page where user can login and see data over a php website hosted locally (available over internet via port forwarding) . But since login would require database to store username/password I want it to be stored on dynamoDb. I think storing online on AWS is a good idea since db will grow over time but php page can be stored and moved easily . Another reason I would like to try is whilst I will get to learn how to use NoSql on dynamo db!

Please guide me the right path to host php locally that uses Amazon dynamoDb  for storing logins?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly connect to DynamoDB from outside of the Amazon environment as long as you have your credentials.  The [PHP Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.PHP.html) should give you most of what you need.

When you're ready to move to an EC2 instance, a t2.nano machine is about USD $4.32 per month.  That would let you setup a full PHP server that could also talk to the database and you wouldn't have to have it locally.

Comment: Thanks, so for having database online on Amazon cloud I would just have to change the end point.

Comment: Actually, no - the endpoint would still be the same.  You would have to get your credentials onto the EC2 instance but that is pretty easy with IAM roles.  Otherwise it should be a simple transition.

Comment: But EC2 does not fall under free tier, that would mean it would be deleted after 1 year. Or I would have to pay to keep an instance with IAM rules!

Comment: It would cost money.  It isn't too expensive but it's not free.

Comment: Dream is bit shattered then, not being able just to host login db on Amazon dynamoDb with php application running locally or on different web server